# Getting the mime type Box api without using a separate head request?

Tags: box-api, box

Is there a way to get the mime type of a file from box.com from just the metadata? Or are we stuck making a HEAD request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Box API doesn't expose file MIME types. You'll have to infer it from the file extension. [Here's a listing](https://docs.box.com/reference#file-object) of the available properties on `file` objects.